# index.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined at index.js:8,

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm not sure how to exactly do this. but  I can give it a try. I need help on this code, and I've provided the code that i believe is relevant to answering the question. I'm trying to get my code to send an alert when there is a key pressed on the website, although every time I run it  It never works. I've looked at the dev tools in chrome and it said I got that error on chrome(my question). I looked through the html as some have said by it hasn't worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>

  </div>







  <footer>
    Made with ❤️ in London.
  </footer>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I also looked at my java-script code and saw if there was any syntax error and I dont think there was, although since I am new, it may be on my part. I've tried to put my js code in "window.onload=function(){
-- put your code here
}" but this hasn't worked and just didn't give me the desired result.If there is something I am missing or didn't do please help me, also I know keypressed is depreciated and so I used keydown, which I thought was my error, but it still didnt work. I would be greatly thankful to anyone that can assist me on this, I really enjoy programming thus far and I know these are the first steps to a very long journey. ??

```
for (var i = 0;i <= document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {



      var buttonInnerHtml = this.innerHTML;

      switch (buttonInnerHtml) {
        case "w":
          var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
          crash.play();
          break;

        case "a":
          var kickBass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
          kickBass.play();
          break;
        case "s":
          var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
          snare.play();
          break;
        case "d":
          var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
          tom1.play();
          break;
        case "j":
          var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
          tom2.play();
          break;
        case "k":
          var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
          tom3.play();
          break;
        case "l":
          var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
          tom4.play();
          break;

        default: console.log(buttonInnerHtml);

      }


  } );

}

document.addEventListener("keydown", drumKeys());

function drumKeys(){
  alert("Key was pressed!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the loop

it should be

```
for (var i = 0;i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++){
```

because you are looping one extra element in the last iteration the value of `document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i]` will be `undefined`.

Comment: It worked tho now it's causing the alert("The key was pressed") to run first before eveyrhting on the page loads.

Comment: this should be changed to `document.addEventListener("keydown", drumKeys);`. the adding the () will call the function directly instead of waiting for callback.

Comment: Thanks, I'm honored for you to have taught me this information.